# Flutter fii - The method 'calloc' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, ffi

I need to use pointers to use ffi with c code..
But when I call the method calloc:

`

```
final p = calloc<Int32>(100);
```

`

I get compilation error: The method 'calloc' isn't defined for the type...

Is there something I missed i did import to:
`

```
import 'dart:ffi';
```

`

Thanks!

Comment: After few hours it's suddenly works!! nothing done really.. weird

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same issue. All of the documentation I can find points to using calloc, do you have any idea how you got it working?

Comment: maybe try to restart the vs code, I really done nothing to solve, it's seem to be a bug in the compiler

Comment: I've figured it out - you need to add `ffi` dependency to `pubspec.yaml` and use it alongside `dart:ffi` import. My file therefore contains both `import 'dart:ffi'; ` and `import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';`.

Comment: How did you fix it?